# Unix: Append each element of a second column to each element of the firsts

Tags: bash, unix, cartesian-product

I’m not a seasoned programmer and I’ve not been able to find a solution to the following. Forgive me if I phrase it incorrectly (this may be a problem with my searching)

I have two single column files

```
A
B
C
```

and

```
X
Y
Z
```

I would like to create a single file that appends every element of the second column to each of the first to get:

```
AX
AY
AZ
BX
BY
BZ
CX
CY
CZ
```

The order of the result isn’t important (e.g., AX, BX, ... would be fine).

Most examples I see use cut and paste, but that only gives part of the solution I’m looking for.

I’m open to any method, but if it’s possible to do it in the bash shell I would prefer that.

Many thanks.

JPG

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output, formatted using the editors `{}` button for readability. If your input is line delimited then don't show it comma delimited and tell us its line delimited - show it line delimited. We need you to provide input/output we can copy/paste as-is to test a potential solution against.

Comment: When you say `if it’s possible to do it in the bash shell I would prefer that.` - do you mean using bash builtins (if so, why?) or with standard UNIX commands like grep, sed, awk, etc. or something else?

Comment: @jpg please check if my edit follows your intention. @Léa's solution dealing with `IFS` seems to be based on a misreading of your problem setting

Comment: problem setting changed after I submitted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

file1='a.txt'
file2='b.txt'

array2="$(cat "${file2}")"

for i in $(cat "${file1}"); do
  for j in ${array2}; do
    echo "${i}${j}"
  done
done
```

Comment: Since file1 and 2 are only referenced once, I don't see much sense in the extra reference. And for array1, there is no reason to use it, too - the cat-command would work fine instead, while in the case of array2, it can be justified to avoid reading the same file over and over again. Beside from that, it's the best, clearest and straightforward solution. +1.

Comment: @userunknown Answer updated to only prefetch file2 in array2 for the inner loop but read file1 in the outer loop

Answer (score 0):

This is probably going to be slow with large file but this works too:

```
cat file1.txt | xargs -d ' ' -I var sh -c 'for i in `cat file2.txt`; do echo var$i; done'
```

```
AX
AY
AZ
BX
BY
BZ
CX
CY
CZ
```

**EDIT**
this might be more efficient by writing the contents of the second file to a variable first

```
SECOND_FILE=$(cat file2.txt) | cat file1.txt | xargs -d ' ' -I var sh -c 'for i in `echo $SECOND_FILE`; do echo var$i; done'
```

If you want to know about this command and others I recommend [explain shell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cat+file1.txt+%7C+xargs+-d+%27+%27+-I+var+sh+-c+%27for+i+in+%60cat+file2.txt%60%3B+do+echo+var%24i%3B+done%27)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done simply with `awk` by storing the values from each file in an array and then simply outputting the values utilizing a nested set of `for` loops, e.g.

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {a[i++] = $1}
    FNR < NR {b[j++] = $1}
    END { 
        for (i in a)
            for (j in b)
                printf "%s%s\n", a[i], b[j] }
' file1 file2
```

The command work by comparing the `FNR` (file record number) with the `NR` (total number of records) seen. If they are equal, you are reading the first file, store the lines in the array `a`. If `NR > FNR`, you are reading the second file, store the lines in array `b`. The within `END`, just output the arrays using nested loops for the desired output. (you can add a validation at the beginning of `END`, e.g. `if (i != j)` to validate an equal number of records from each if that is a criteria)

Given your two files shown stored as `file1` and `file2` would result in the following output:

```
AX
AY
AZ
BX
BY
BZ
CX
CY
CZ
```

(you can simply select the `awk` command and then middle-mouse paste it into your terminal to test, e.g.)

```
$ awk '
>     FNR == NR {a[i++] = $1}
>     FNR < NR {b[j++] = $1}
>     END {
>         for (i in a)
>             for (j in b)
>                 printf "%s%s\n", a[i], b[j] }
> ' file1 file2
AX
AY
AZ
BX
BY
BZ
CX
CY
CZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
with one bonus ... it filters out empty lines from the two input files

```
jq -rn --rawfile f1 file1.txt --rawfile f2 file2.txt 
  'def seq: split("\n")[] | select(length > 0);
   {a: $f1|seq, b: $f2|seq} | .a + .b'
```